# regex for partial urls

Tags: regex

does anyone know how to write the regex for this list of urls for workbox

```
/
/tracker/patientlist
/tracker/visitlist
/tracker/triage
```

i am new to regex

Comment: Can you elaborate on the rule? Which ones pass and which ones fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to match the root url `/`, or `/tracker/*`, try this:

```
/(tracker/\w+)?
```

Comment: i tested online tool and its failing for / and /tracker/patientlist or any other url

Comment: That's probably because the "on line tool" expects you to escape the back slashes: try entering it as `\/(tracker\/\w+)?`. Note that back slash escaping has nothnig whatsoever to do with regex - it is a choice by tool/langauges that use a slash to *delimit* regex

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.(Not sure what other URI variations you may have, but this should do it). If the first part is always `/tracker`, then use Bohemian's answer.

```
(\/[a-zA-Z]+)
```